# Webpack can't process svg Files after Modules updates

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am having an issue with my .svg files. I had to update Node and many modules to the latest version and remove lots of deprecated modules or unused ones. Since then, I can't build anymore.

This is the part of the code that is causing my issue :

```
&.icon-ned-bag {
        background: url(../images/Interface/bag.svg) no-repeat 50% / contain;
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
    }
```

The path is 100% correct but when I am doing "npm run build". I have the following error :
"Can't resolve '../images/Interface/bag.svg'".

I am quite sure it comes from my webpack because it was working in the past. I have googled and tried many things with FileLoader or the new webpack5 (currently using that) but nothing is working and it seems I am missing something.

This is the current Webpack :

```
const path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin'),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'), 
    MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const
    PUBLIC_PATH = process.env.PUBLIC_PATH,
    NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const
    language = 'fr';

let
    entrypoints = [],
    plugins = [];

if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    entrypoints.push(
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
    );
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new WriteFilePlugin({
            test: /\.css$/
        })
    );
}

module.exports = {
//This is trimed on purpose so it's shorter
    entry: {
        useredit: [
            "./Content/scss/desktop/pages/useredit.scss"
        ]
    },
    output: { 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "js/bundle_[name].js",
        publicPath: '/'
    },
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'babel-loader',
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Filename for the extracted CSS file
            filename: 'css/[name].css',
            // Filename for the extracted CSS file for the chunks (dynamic imports)
            chunkFilename: 'css/[id].css',
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".css", ".scss"]
    },
    devtool: NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    stats: "errors-only",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        index: '',
        proxy: {
            '/': 'http://localhost:12533'
        }
    }
}
```

But I also have tried the following :

```
{
    test: /\.svg/,
    type: 'asset/inline'
},
```

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
},
```

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

```
{
   test: /\.svg$/,
   use: [
   {
        loader: "@svgr/webpack"
   },
   {
        loader: "file-loader"
    }
    ],
    type: "javascript/auto",
    issuer: {
         and: [/\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|md|mdx)$/]
    }
},
```

I tried to follow this documentation also but it didn't work.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

I am quite unfamiliar with Node, so it may be something obvious that is missing but I can't find it.

If anybody has some tips or an example of how to do it. That would be so helpful

Thanks a lot for your time

Extra information (package.json)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "blazy": "^1.8.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "siema": "^1.5.1",
    "underscore": "^1.13.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "browserslist": "cover 95%, ie >= 10",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@adyen/adyen-web": "^5.47.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "browserslist": "^4.21.9",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.9.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "main": "postcss.config.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```